# MongoDb - Importing a large Json file with one million records through java - Out of Memory error

Tags: java, json, mongodb, import

I am trying to import a json file with around 1 million records into MongoDb using the following java api and I am getting Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I tried increasing the java heap space in my eclipse settings but still getting the same error. If the total records in the json is less than 500k, the program is working fine without any issues. But,once the records went around 600k in the json document, I am getting this error. I was able to import the same json file through mongoimport from command prompt without any issues. Can anyone please help me in fixing this program so that I should be able to import large data sets into mongo with java application.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("Sample");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Sample_690000");

int count = 0;
int batch = 10000;

List<InsertOneModel<Document>> docs = new ArrayList<>();

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new FileReader("C:\\\\CsvFiles\\SampleDataJSON690000.json"))) {
    String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Document document = Document.parse(String.format("{\"a\": %s}", line));

            for(Document doc : (ArrayList<Document>)document.get("a")) {
                docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(doc));
                count++;
            }
            if(count == batch) {
                collection.bulkWrite(docs, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
                docs.clear();
                count = 0;
        }
    }
}
if(count > 0) {
    collection.bulkWrite(docs, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the size of your inner arrays changes for some entries towards the end of the file? The problem doesn't seem obvious. But a growing value of the `a` arrays could possibly explain this...

Comment: No, I don't think the size changes. This is my sample data, I have the file with this kind of data for 600k transactions and it is giving me the out of memory error.                                                                  
[{"TRANSACTION DATE":"2018-02-11","PRIMARY ID":"20001","PRIMARY FIRST NAME":"ABC","PRIMARY LAST NAME":"XYZ","PRIMARY CITY":"HONOLULU","PRIMARY STATE":"HI","PRIMARY ZIP":"33344"},{"TRANSACTION DATE":"2018-02-11","PRIMARY ID":"20002","PRIMARY FIRST NAME":"BCD","PRIMARY LAST NAME":"XYC","PRIMARY CITY":"PONTE VEDRA","PRIMARY STATE":"FL","PRIMARY ZIP":"12345"}]